# How to get location data faster with using LocationManager in Android

Tags: java, android, gps

I want to take the location information. Here is the code snippet that I used:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "The velocity calculator does not work if you do not give the permisson ..!"
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 0, this);
    }
```

And in the onLocationChanged method, I get the location. The problem is that this method takes location about in every 10 seconds. But I want to get much more faster like getting every second. Can I achieve that with againusing locationManager. If not, what is the other solutions?

Comment: use google api client for accurate and fast updates

Comment: visit my github page, i just uploaded googlemap location. https://github.com/kopilim96/android-google-Maps